# Analytic continuation of Euler's reflection formula with the Gamma function

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, gamma-function, residue-calculus

> Let $\widetilde\Gamma$ be an analytic continuation of $\Gamma$ on $\mathbb C\setminus(-\mathbb N_0)$. Show that the function
>   $$\widetilde\Gamma(z)\widetilde\Gamma(1-z)-\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)}$$
>   can be analytically continued to an entire function.

I do assume that the analytic continuation is the classical $$\widetilde\Gamma(z)=\frac{\Gamma(z+n)}{z(z+1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(z+n-1)}$$ 
for $z\in\mathbb C\setminus(-\mathbb N_0),\operatorname{Re} z>-n$ with residues $$\operatorname{Res}_{-n}(\widetilde\Gamma)=\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}$$ with $n\in\mathbb{N}_0$ which I had to deduce in the excersice leading to this problem. I stumbled upon explanations on how to compute $\widetilde\Gamma(z)\widetilde\Gamma(1-z)$ using the Beta function I am not familiar with. Now I am curious as to what I have to do exactly with the given function and which methods there are available to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "standard" analytic continuation leads to to Euler's limit product formula, that leads to the Weierstrass product:
$$ \Gamma(z)=\frac{e^{-\gamma z}}{z}\prod_{n\geq 1}\left(1+\frac{z}{n}\right)^{-1}e^{z/n} \tag{1}$$
from which:
$$ z\,\Gamma(z)\Gamma(-z)=\frac{1}{z}\prod_{n\geq 1}\left(1-\frac{z^{2}}{n^2}\right)^{-1}\tag{2}$$
and you may finish the work by recognizing the (reciprocal) Weierstrass product for a sine function in the RHS.

> As an alternative, you may just prove that
>   $\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)-\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)}$ has no singular point,
>   since both terms have simple poles at the same points with the same
>   residues: $$\text{Res}\left(\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z),z=-n\right)=(-1)^n,$$
>   $$\text{Res}\left(\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)},z=-n\right)=\lim_{z\to
>  n}\frac{\pi(z-n)}{\sin(\pi z)}\stackrel{DH}{=}\cos(\pi
>  n)=(-1)^n.\tag{3}$$

Yet another way is to prove the red equality:
$$\frac{d^2}{dz^2}\log(\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z))=\psi''(z)+\psi''(1-z)=\sum_{n\geq 0}\left(\frac{1}{(z+n)^2}+\frac{1}{(1-z+n)^2}\right)\color{red}{=}\frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2(\pi z)}=\frac{d^2}{dz^2}\log\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)}\tag{4}$$
through Fourier series or other means.

Comment: I'd rather keep it simple and stick to the argument that the function has no singular points - this isn't that obvious to me, though. For $\Gamma$ we would have to multiply $\Gamma(z)$ with every $(z+n)$ for each $\mathbb N_0\ni n< z$, wouldn't we? So how can it be that the expression will in fact be defined where $\sin(\pi z)$ is clearly difficult to handle.

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic: from $\text{Res}(\Gamma(z),z=-n)=\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}$ it follows that $\text{Res}(\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z),z=-n)=(-1)^n$, so you just have to check that the residues of the cosecant match.

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic: that is simple to show through De l'Hopital's theorem since $\cos(\pi n)=(-1)^n$.

Comment: I never stumbled upon this argumentation - did I understand you correctly that $f(z) + g(z)$ is considered entire with no singularities when their residues match s.t. that they "cancel" out? If so, where does this result come from?

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic: it is slightly different. Here we have two meromorphic functions $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ with simple poles at the integers. If their residues match, then $f(z)-g(z)$ is an entire function (as a meromorphic function without poles).

Comment: Then you just have to prove that $f(z)-g(z)$ is bounded over the right half-plane to have that $f(z)-g(z)$ is constant by Liouville's theorem. Such a constant is zero by evaluating both functions at $z=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Could you elaborate why the function is bounded? Furthermore is it possible to argue without knowing $\Gamma(1/2)$? Concerning Liouville I see your point and yet I would need to know that the LHS is $\pi$.

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic: the first proof of such fact that came to my mind exploits $(4)$. You may avoid $\Gamma(1/2)$ by computing $\lim_{z\to 0^+}\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)$.

Comment: I am still on the look out for some alternative ways to argument since I don't have that many tools at hand. Analyzing your suggested limit yields $\infty$ for both terms however an expression of the form $\infty-\infty$ isn't as solid as your suggested $z=1/2$ assuming I would have been working with equation $(4)$. Do you have further references on why $f-g$ will have no poles and other suggestions on how to work with Liouville since it seems to be the most elegant way to show the claim? Furthermore why does $\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)$ have a residue but no poles - are there other singularities?

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic: sorry, I meant $$\lim_{z\to 0^+}\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)-\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)}.$$ That is doable through DH as $$ \lim_{z\to 0^+}\frac{\Gamma(1+z)\Gamma(1-z)-\frac{\pi z}{\sin(\pi z)}}{z}.$$

Comment: About the second point, you should know that $\Gamma(z)$ is holomorphic in the right half-plane and has a simple pole at $z=0$. By continuing the $\Gamma$ function through $\Gamma(z+1)=z\,\Gamma(z)$, it follows that the only singularities of $\Gamma(z)$ are simple poles at $0$ and the negative integers.

Comment: What can we derive from evaluating the particular limit for $z\to 0^+$? Basically that the expression can be analytically continued at $0$ but how propagates this for all singularities? I have a feeling that the same argument will apply to all $z\to n\in-\mathbb N_0$, isn't it?

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic: that limit is obviously related with $z=0$ being a simple pole with residue $1$, the propagation is so always the same induced by $\Gamma(z+1)=z\Gamma(z)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the thorough explanations - thus far there remains one last question. I do see how you expanded the last limit with $z/z$ and applied the recurrence relation but I am not sure how you deduce the limit in the end - do you derive $\Gamma$ as well as $\pi z/\sin(\pi z)$ or do you apply some identities and tricks to make it much simpler to evaluate?

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic: it is a simple trick: both $\frac{\pi z}{\sin(\pi z)}$ and $\Gamma(1+z)\Gamma(1-z)$ are analytic and **even** functions in a neighbourhood of $z=0$, so that limit is clearly zero as: $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{h(x^2)}{x}=0$$ with $h$ being an analytic function fulfilling $h(0)=0$.

Comment: Wow this is really unexpected - thanks for bearing with me.

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic: you're welcome.

Comment: I came back to notify you that I might have up with an alternative and prosaic explanation of your first suggestion which helped me understand it. Since both terms have simple poles at the same points with the same residues their difference implies that the principal parts of their Laurent expansions cancel which shows that the given function is indeed entire.

Answer (score 0):

The Laplace transform of $t^{-1+\alpha}$ for $\alpha > 0$ is given by the following for $s > 0$:
\begin{align}
  \mathscr{L}\{t^{-1+\alpha}\} & = \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-st}t^{-1+\alpha}dt \\
    & = \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-st}(st)^{-1+\alpha}d(st)\cdot s^{-\alpha} \\
    & = \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-u}u^{-1+\alpha}du\cdot s^{-\alpha}=\Gamma(\alpha)s^{-\alpha}
\end{align}
Because of this,
\begin{align}
 \frac{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}\mathscr{L}\{ t^{-1+\alpha+\beta} \} 
 & = \Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)s^{-\alpha-\beta} \\
   & = \Gamma(\alpha)s^{-\alpha}\Gamma(\beta)s^{-\beta} \\
   & = \mathscr{L}\{ t^{-1+\alpha}\}\mathscr{L}\{ t^{-1+\beta}\} \\
   & = \mathscr{L}\{ t^{-1+\alpha} \star t^{-1+\beta} \}
\end{align}
By uniqueness of transforms, the convolution of $t^{-1+\alpha}$ and $t^{-1+\beta}$ is given by
$$
     t^{-1+\alpha}\star t^{-1+\beta} = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}t^{-1+\alpha+\beta},\;\;\; \alpha,\beta > 0.
$$
If $0 < \alpha < 1$ and $\beta = 1-\alpha$, then
$$
       t^{-1+\alpha}\star t^{-\alpha} = \Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(1-\alpha)
$$
Curiously, the above does not depend on $t > 0$. So, set $t=1$:
$$
     \Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(1-\alpha)=\int_{0}^{1}u^{-1+\alpha}(1-u)^{-\alpha}du.
$$
By turning the integral on the right into a contour integral enclosing $[0,1]$ in its interior, you can show that $F(\alpha)=\sin(\pi\alpha)\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(1-\alpha)$ is a contour integral that has an entire extension. That's enough for what you want. In fact, you can then evaluate the contour integral by a single residue at $\infty$ to obtain the full identity
$$
           \Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)\sin(\pi z) = \pi.
$$